# Excel IF THEN Nested Formula Across Multiple Columns

Tags: excel

I have three columns (col1, col2, and col3) which I need to use a nested formula to output into col4.

The logic is as follows:

- IF col3 = `Yes` AND IF (col1 = col2) THEN `Sales Opportunity`
- IF col3 = `Yes` AND IF (col1 <> col2) THEN `Partner Opportunity`
- IF col3 = `No` THEN `""`

So far I've put together a combination of different formulas, none of which seem to create any meaningful results. Two of the following examples:

```
=IF(AND(AX28="Yes",F28=D28),"CLM Opportunity"),IF(AND(AX28="Yes",F28<>D28),"Partner Opportunity","")
```

```
=IF(OR(AND(AX35="Yes",F35=D35),AND(AX35="Yes",F35<>D35)),"CLM Opportunity","Partner Opportunity")
```

How the nested formulas should output:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Amy | Amy | Yes | Sales Op |
| Cedric | Pete | Yes | Partner Op |
| Amelia | Amelia | No |  |

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a nested IF:

```
=IF(C2="Yes",IF(A2=B2,"Sales Op","Partner Op"),"")
```

[image]

Logic:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It wasn't working for a second, but realized I had a different row for col1 and col2 so it wasn't matching correctly :) It's all sorted now.